Spring Repository - Unable to use two data sources for MySQL and Clickhouse
I have two databases, MySQL and Clickhouse.
I created two separate configurations for both DBs:
for MySQL (it is primary):
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEM",
        basePackages = {"com.myproject.repository.mysqlrepos"})
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MySQLDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSourceProperties mysqlDbProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mysql.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource mysqlDataSource(
            DataSourceProperties mysqlDbProperties) {
        return mysqlDbProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlEM")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource mysqlDataSource) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.myproject.entity.mysqlentities")
                .persistenceUnit("mysql")
                .build();
    }
}

for Clickhouse:
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "clickhouseEM",
        basePackages = {"com.myproject.repository.clickhouserepos"})
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ClickhouseDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.clickhouse")
    public DataSourceProperties clickhouseDbProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.clickhouse.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource clickhouseDataSource(
            DataSourceProperties clickhouseDbProperties) {
        return clickhouseDbProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "clickhouseEM")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean clickhouseEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource clickhouseDataSource) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        return builder.dataSource(clickhouseDataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.myproject.entity.clickhouseentities")
                .persistenceUnit("clickhouse")
                .build();
    }
}

All MySQL repositories extend JPARepository.
For Clickhouse however I created a custom repository, with one single method for running native "select" query against Clickhouse.
This is repository interface:
@Repository
public interface MyClickhouseRepository {
    List<MyClickhouseEntity> findSomeoneInClickhouse(String name);
}

And this is its implementation:
@Repository
public class MyClickhouseRepositoryImpl implements MyClickhouseRepository {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("clickhouseEM") EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public List<MyClickhouseEntity> findSomeoneInClickhouse(String name) {
           Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from myschema.mytable final where name = :name", MyClickhouseEntity.class);
           query.setParameter("name", name);

           List<MyClickhouseEntity> res = query.getResultList();
           return res;
        }

}

The app starts up successfully but when I call findSomeoneInClickhouse(String) method of MyClickhouseRepositoryImpl, it drops the error saying:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'myschema', but that database exists in Clickhouse.
And if I run a query having Clickhouse-specific keywords, it drops the error saying:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
Both of these errors show that my app queries only MySQL and doesn't use Clickhouse, even though I'm using clickhouseEM entity manager in repository.
If I remove @Primary annotations from MySQL config, and add them to Clickhouse config, things are reversed - my app queries Clickhouse only, and doesn't use MySQL.
Any ideas what I might be missing here?

It seems that the DataSourceProperties injected in the data source methods is the @Primary one. Make sure that the DataSourceProperties that are injected in the datasource methods are the right for each data source using the @Qualifier annotation:
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mysql.hikari")
public HikariDataSource mysqlDataSource(
        @Qualifier("mysqlDbProperties") DataSourceProperties mysqlDbProperties) {
    return mysqlDbProperties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.clickhouse.hikari")
public HikariDataSource clickhouseDataSource(
        @Qualifier("clickhouseDbProperties") DataSourceProperties clickhouseDbProperties) {
    return clickhouseDbProperties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}

I also think that the @ConfigurationProperties annotation on the data source methods is not needed and you can remove it.

thank you for going through my question, it was indeed due to the absence of @Qualifier annotations. I somehow forgot that beans are detected through names, not types. So both entity managers were using the same primary HikariDataSource
